# How can i display data inside the tablayout?

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio

Inside my detail page activity, i have a tablayout with a corresponding fragments per tab. [photo ref1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2ijU.png) [photoref2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TQQL.png). The contents above before the tablayout was all fetched from the database by using this code inside the adapter

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, DestinationDetailAct.class);
        i.putExtra("name", recommendList.get(position).getPackage_name());
        i.putExtra("region", recommendList.get(position).getPackage_region());
        i.putExtra("country", recommendList.get(position).getPackage_country());
        i.putExtra("videourl", recommendList.get(position).getPackage_video());
        context.startActivity(i);
```

but this would only work with activities. how can i successfully display the additional details inside the fragments of tablayout?

Comment: Can you please explain how is this code related to Firebase?

Comment: All of the data displayed is fetched from firebase, the title, country, poster, video etc.

Comment: And ar you getting the correct data?

Comment: yes but for my tablayout, i cant seem to display any data

Comment: So it's a question more related to the UI, and not to Firebase, right?